# Moved /etc to home directory, now I can't boot, how do I move the directory back?

Tags: 14.04, etc

I made a dumb mistake, and moved the `/etc` directory from where it is.  This is the error I got when I rebooted:

[image]

I can't boot, so now I need to move that directory back to where it was before.

How can I do this, and what steps do I have to take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a Ubuntu live CD and move 'etc' again.

Comment: Or insert your drive into a second running computer to copy it back.

Comment: @Peter Nerlich Or use a third machine to burn a CD 

Comment: yeah it worked , i just moved it like super user with commands : 1.sudo su 2. mv etc/ ..  3. it's moved to root directory where it has to be, and my Pc is booting good again

Comment: Simple, elegant, 100% correct!